# Hexo, nav active state

Tags: hyperlink, nav, hexo

I am new to Hexo and wondering if there is a way of adding an a:active state to a nav item of the current page?

HTML...

```
<nav>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a href="index.html">INDEX</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```

CSS...

```
a:active {
   color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all - the `a:active` is not meant to be set by the server - the `:active` pseudo-class means that the element has been activated by user - read more [in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active)

What you really want here is an anchor tag marked by a regular class when its href equals to the currently visited URL. In Hexo, you can do it by using [the `is_active` helper](https://hexo.io/docs/helpers.html#is-current):

Thus, your code may look like this (adding additional `is-active` class to anchor when it 
 is the current page):

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="index.html" class="link <% if(is_current('index.html')) { %>is-active<% } %>">INDEX</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
<nav>
```

CSS:

```
a.is-active {
  color:green;
}
```